# Start jar app from Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, jar

I have **two** java application,

1. Spring Boot application which should start
2. Second application java application via /start-app, this app should run parallel to spring-boot app

The process is starting but it seems to be in kind of idle mode.
after closing the Spring Boot application the java-app.jar is starting to work properly :-/.

Thank you.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class Controller {

    @PostMapping(value = "/start-app", produces = "application/json")
    public void startJavaApp(@RequestBody ObjectString objectString) throws IOException {

        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar java-app.jar");

        CompletableFuture.runAsync(()-> {
            try {
                proc.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which works for me here

https://www.infoworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class Controller {

    @PostMapping(value = "/start-app", produces = "application/json")
    public void startJavaApp(@RequestBody ObjectString objectString) throws IOException {

        try
        {

            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("run.bat");
            InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
      
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    //logger.info("Java java-app stream has been started");
                    String line = null;
                    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                        logger.info(line);
                        System.out.println(line);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            });

        } catch (Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```